# Plot the solution and Inverse as well

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions, inverse

I used this code to solve an equation and now I would like to plot the solution with its inverse. I can't get some figures?!!

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqns = {Derivative[1][y][
 x] + (3/2)*(a - b)*(y[x]/x) - ((3/2)*a - 1)*(1/(y[x]*x^3)) == 0}
 sol = FullSimplify[DSolve[eqns, y[x], x]]
 y2[x_] = y[x] /. sol[[2]];
 DSolve[{y2[x[t]] == Derivative[1][x][t]/x[t]}, x[t], t]
 a = 1.3; b = 0.7; Plot[(
 2 Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (3 (a - b))/(-4 + 6 a - 6 b), (
 4 - 9 a + 9 b)/(4 - 6 a + 6 b), ((2 - 3 a) #1^(-2 + 3 a - 3 b))/((-2 + 3 a - 3 b) C[
 1])] Sqrt[1 + ((-2 + 3 a) #1^(-2 + 3 a - 3 b))/((-2 + 3 a - 3 b) C[1])])/(
 3 (a - b) Sqrt[(-2 + 3 a)/#1^2 + (-2 + 3 a - 3 b) C[
 1] #1^(-3 a + 3 b)]), {#1, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133552/discussion-on-question-by-felipe-dura-plot-the-solution-and-inverse-as-well).

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying `a,b`, introduce an initial condition `y[1]==y1` in your ode. `DSolve` evaluates two solutions depending on `x,y1,a,b`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol = FullSimplify[DSolve[{Derivative[1][y][x] + (3/2)*(a - b)*(y[x]/x) - ((3/2)*a - 1)*(1/(y[x]*x^3)) == 0, y[1] == y1}, y[x], x]]
```

$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to -\frac{\sqrt{x^{3 b-3 a}\left(\text{y1}^2 (3 a-3 b-2)-3 a+2\right)+\frac{3a-2}{x^2}}}{\sqrt{3 a-3 b-2}}\right\},\left\{y(x)\to\frac{\sqrt{x^{3 b-3 a} \left(\text{y1}^2 (3 a-3 b-2)-3a+2\right)+\frac{3 a-2}{x^2}}}{\sqrt{3 a-3b-2}}\right\}\right\}$

Plot special solution

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol /. {y1 -> 3/10, a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

The plot shows that the `InverseFunction` exists only piecewise!

**addendum**

Second ode seems symbolically not easily solvable. Therefore numerical solution is appropriate. The second ode is transformed to `t'[x]==1/(x y[x])`, now it's possible to solve the two odes for `t[x],y[x]` in one step:

```
ty = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][y][x] + (3/2)*(a - b)*(y[x]/x) - ((3/2)*a - 1)*(1/(y[x]*x^3)) ==      0, y[1] == y1, t'[x] == 1/(x y[x]), t[1] == 0} /. {y1 -> 3/10, a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10}, {t, y}, {x, 1, 10}, y1]  

ParametricPlot[{{ty[1][[1]][x], ty[1][[2]][x]}, {ty[1][[1]][x] , x}}, {x, 1, 10}, AxesLabel -> {t, "y[t],x[t]"},AspectRatio-> 1/3,PlotLegends -> {"y"[t], "x[t]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: You just plot the first part which is easy I would like to do for the second DSolve[]

Comment: Plot shows both parts of sol (but not the inverse)

Comment: As you see in my code the plots should be x[t] and y[t]. but you just plot y[x]!!

Comment: Ulrich Neumann,  t'[x]==1/(x y[x])  ?????!!!!! how? I guess it is x'[t]==1/(x y[x])

Comment: `t'[x]==1/(x y[x])` is equivalent to the ode `x'[t]/x[t]==y[x[t]]`

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that your second `DSolve` gives the inverse of `y`.  In any case, it is easy to plot the inverse.  With Ulrich Neumann's answer as a starting plot, use

```
ParametricPlot[{{(y[x] /. sol)[[2]] /. {y1 -> 3/10, a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10}, x},
                {(y[x] /. sol)[[1]] /. {y1 -> 3/10, a -> 13/10, b -> 7/10}, x}}, 
                {x, 1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 2, AxesLabel -> {y, x}]
```

[image]

However, if you really do wish to plot the result of the second `DSolve`, designate it as `soli` and extract an equation for `t` as a function of `x`.

```
soli[[1, 1, 2, 1]] == soli[[1, 1, 2, 0, 1]][x]
Sqrt[10] # & /@ % /. {a -> 4, b -> 0, C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}

(* t == (Sqrt[5/2] Sqrt[1 + x^10] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 3/5, 8/5, 
       -x^10])/(3 Sqrt[10/x^12 + 10/x^2]) *)
```

(I have chosen the constants for convenience.  Other values also work.)  Then, use `ParametricPlot` as before.

```
ParametricPlot[{%[[2]], x}, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image]

There are, of course, other ways to plot inverses of functions.  The method shown seems simplest to me

Comment: bbgodfrey I can't see soli[[1, 1, 2, 1]] is working??!! even with sol[[1, 1, 2, 1]]  
bbgodfrey

Comment: @FelipeDura  Sorry for the slow response.  I fixed a typo in the secod `ParametricPlot` call

Comment: bbgodfrey this code you put here it's not working

Comment: @FelipeDura  I just ran the code, and it provides the curve shown in my answer.  In what sense is my code not working?